# How to add textfield to google maps ios

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I am working on a project where I take the information from the textfield and then use it to geocode for the lat and long. However, I am having problems with implementing a uitextfield that responds when it is clicked. At the moment, I can see my textfield but it doesnt respond at all to any gesture. After searching online for hours, i was also wondering if google maps sdk had a search box that you can implement.

I read online that google maps has a gmsblockinggesturerecognizer, but when i took the steps to counter it, nothing seemed to happen.

How do you add a search bar/ textfield for your address search on your maps?!

Comment: You should use `UISearchController` which is new in iOS 8. You can check out [this tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift) for more details about how to implement `UISearchController`